# How I can delete a specific variable names in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, variables, del

Here's the data:

```
id  date    age case_id country province    region  sex travel  travelh
1   1516    2020-03-23  40-49   1516    Canada  Ontario York    Male    1   Costa Rica
4   5658    2020-03-29  60-69   5657    Canada  Ontario Algoma  Female  1   United States
5   642 2020-03-18  Not Reported    642 Canada  Nova Scotia Not Reported    Not Reported    1   Not Reported
6   3560    2020-03-26  60-69   3560    Canada  Ontario Simcoe Muskoka  Male    1   India, United Arab Emirates
7   725 2020-03-18  80-89   725 Canada  Ontario Chatham-Kent    Female  1   United States
```

I wrote

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

but it did not work for all "Not Reported". Is there any ways to delete "not reported" rows in the dataset?

Comment: `dropna()` drops `NaN` values. `Not Reported` is not the same as `NaN`.

Comment: Presumably 'Not Reported' is a string; then you can use `df = df.replace('Not Reported', np.nan).dropna()`

Comment: Do you want to replace all `Not Reported` with 'NA` or '0`?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete rows with `Not Reported` values in your dataset using the following code:

```
df = df[df != 'Not Reported'].dropna(how='any')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `Not Reported` to `None`

```
df = df.replace('Not Reported', None).dropna()
```